# submit Facebook messaging app for review steps

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

Facebook api is one of the oddest apis I have ever seen, everything is vague and weird, I could finish my app which basically listens for users DM in Instagram and responds back to them automatically.

I connected my own Facebook page which is connected to Instagram and I can send message to myself through my other account and it works.

Yet apparently I am supposed to submit for review before it works for other people who DM me, in the steps it mentions that they have to be able to connect via Facebook login to it otherwise they would reject it.

I'm not sure I quite understand I should build something that lets them connect their own Facebook page to this app? Just like I connected mine?

I was wondering how I could add clients, but I though everyone of them should create their own app not everyone using mine, would the rate limit even allow such a thing?

Comment: _"I was wondering how I could add clients"_ - implement login, and ask them for the relevant permissions?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for responding that's nice of you, do you mind just listing the steps? The user logins he/she becomes a part of the app and a I can access their pages? Or are there any extra steps? ( I know I should get user token then page id then page token )

Comment: You ask for whatever permission(s) the endpoints you are intending to use require, and once the user has granted those to your app, you make the necessary API calls ... Yes, so far, in a nutshell. Which permissions are required, is usually explicitly explained in the documentation.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! You might as well post that as the answer! Just one last question so imagine I have 10 clients they all connect to the same app and everyone will be using the chat bot which I created, thousands of messages will be exchanged in few minutes probably, using the same app, is this the right way to implement it? Won't rate limiting shut everything down? (By the way my whole app is just a chatbot it gets data from webhook and responds using the messaging api)

Comment: If you add more pages, then the number of "engaged users" should grow along with it, increasing your rate limits accordingly. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/overview#rate-limiting

Comment: @CBroe Thank you :) you really helped me a lot I was confused